# redirecion en PHP

Tags: php, html

necesito redireccionar desde una subcarpeta(pasteleria/ajax_cotixar/cotizar.php) a la carpeta principal donde esta todo el proyecto(pasteleria), cuando quiero redireccionar me dice "404 not found", y me muestra una ruta (localhost)/pasteleria/ajax_cotizar/perfil.php.

osea, redireccionar desta:
(localhost)/pasteleria/ajax_cotizar/cotiar.php

hasta:
(localhost)/pasteleria/perfil.php

GRACIAS

Comment: agrega el codigo

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).